# How can I mimic the VC trigger behavior of modular synthesis with the WebAudio API?

Tags: javascript, web, audio, synthesis

I have this picture: http://bourt.com/color/slide.html. Left-clicking the circle will generate an audible click. I want the clicks to be constant until I release the mouse button, and to make the interval between the clicks smaller as I move the circle up, to the point where the clicks form a tone.

I can get the gist of what I need with a simple tone (http://bourt.com/color/slide1.html), but I would like the LFO to trigger the envelope which I use for creating the click.

It's easy to do in VCV, which is where I prototyped this:
[image]

But I can't quite figure out how to mimic the behavior of triggering the envelope with an LFO. As I understand it, one option is to use `AnalyserNode.getFloatTimeDomainData()`, find the peaks and schedule the clicks accordingly. Another would be to forego the LFO concept altogether and use a ScriptProcessor as a makeshift mixer by adding the clicks to the buffer manually. But that's a lot of damn work for something that is conceptually very simple.

So I'm still hoping that it's possible to somehow use an oscillator to trigger the clicks, and vary the frequency of that oscillator with the position of the circle. Is it?

(I am aware of [The Tale Of Two Clocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/), but I don't think this kind of scheduling will work for the upper part of the slider where the clicks are so close that they create a tone.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the `setTimeout()` scheduling method, it became clear that the only way to achieve this is by using `ScriptProcessorNode` and adding the clicks to the audio buffer myself. It's similar to the scheduling method, but all the samples have to be handled manually, which is a pain, but it's what I ended up doing.

For those curious, here's what the code looks like (the important parts):

```
var clickProc       = null;
var clickBuffer     = null;

var clickSample     = 0;
var remSamples      = 0;

var remBuffer       = null;
var remBufferLength = 0;


remBuffer = new Float32Array(2048);
clickProc = ac.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);


clickProc.onaudioprocess = function (e)
{
    var output = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    var click  = clickBuffer.getChannelData(0);


    for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
        output[i] = 0;


    if (remBufferLength > 0)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < remBufferLength; i++)
            output[i] = remBuffer[i];

        remBufferLength = 0;
    }


    for (i = 0; i < remBuffer.length; i++)
        remBuffer[i] = 0;


    if (clickSample >= output.length)
        clickSample -= output.length;


    while (clickSample < output.length)
    {
        var c;

        for (c = 0; c < click.length && clickSample < output.length; c++, clickSample++)
            output[clickSample] = Math.min(Math.max(0, output[clickSample] + click[c]), 1);

        remSamples = click.length - c;

        clickSample -= c;
        clickSample += Math.max(1, Math.floor(clickInterval * ac.sampleRate));


        if (c < click.length)
        {
            var remLength = click.length - c;

            for (i = 0; i < remLength; i++, c++)
                remBuffer[i] = Math.min(Math.max(0, remBuffer[i] + click[c]), 1);

            remBufferLength = Math.max(remBufferLength, remLength);
        }
    }
};

clickProc.connect(ac.destination);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using logic circuitry (eg: LFO-based) would be painful indeed. I suggest you use a setTimeout based method to register future clicks while still using the sound clock as a reference for triggering the play. I once built an audiotracker in JS and this was the most straightforward solution. My own code is quite messy but I found a great example [over here](https://github.com/wktdev/sequencer/blob/master/js/app.js#L143)

Comment: Actually, using an LFO would be the easiest way to do this IF WebAudio could simulate control voltage. But it can't, so... yeah. :) As for `setTimeout()`, wouldn't that only work for beats? As the click rate increases (especially when the clicks are so close they form a tone), would this still work? Because it seems that I'd have to schedule more and more clicks per `setTimeout()` call, and keep track of the timings anyway.

Comment: Ok, so as you suggested I went ahead and used `setTimeout()'. Here is the result: http://bourt.com/color/slide2.html. Honestly, this is a poor man's version of what I really want, which is this: https://youtu.be/W2e4Ow4x-nQ  Is this the limit of what's achievable with this method? Does this mean I have to use ScriptProcessor and do the synthesis manually?

Comment: I did not understand that you wanted to use click as a mean of synthesizing the continuous waveform, I thought you would use it as a metronome hence the scheduler method (which is acceptable for non-overlapping clicks).
Maybe you could achieve this with Frequency Modulation, with a silent carrier (null amplitude) and a square wave modulator, but then you would lose the envelope on the click ...

Comment: ... or you could record your click and handle the PCM arrayBuffer directly, but then there is no point using the WebAudio API except for its clock precision...